# Tensorflow js Model.executeAsync() gives output of 1 or 0

Tags: android, react-native, expo, object-detection, tensorflow.js

I have a trained ssd mobilenet tensorflow js model(I have tested the model and it has good accuracy). I have loaded the weights and model.json files in my react native app as follows with no errors.

```
const modelJson = require("./assets/tfjsexport/model.json");

      const modelWeights = [
        require("./assets/tfjsexport/group1-shard1of3.bin"),
        require("./assets/tfjsexport/group1-shard2of3.bin"),
        require("./assets/tfjsexport/group1-shard3of3.bin"),
      ];


      const roiModel = await tf.loadGraphModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJson, modelWeights)).catch((e) => {
        console.log("[LOADING ERROR] info:", e)
      })
```

I get the predictions of the model with this code

```
  const predictionsData = await model.executeAsync(imagesTensor);
```

My app is a managed Expo App.

**Describe your problem in more detail.**

Whenever I use the Debug Remote JS feature (which allows me to use the React native Debugger on my pc), I get Good reasonable prediction values from my model. like the screenshot below.
[prediction values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1kcs.png)

But whenever I stop using the Remote debugger, the values display either '1' or '0'.
[1 or 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5lS1.png)

I thought they were all rounded up values. I decided to do a sanity check by inserting those '1' or '0' to do further calculations like eg Determining the predicted classes, getting bounding boxes etc. But it was clear that they were actually '1' and '0' and are not useful prediction values in terms of object detection.

I switched back to the Remote React native Debugger and I started getting good prediction values.

**Describe what you tried and what you expected to happen**
I tried using

```
tensor.print()
```

and

```
console.log(tensor)
```

to print the tensor values obtained from the model, but I got the same '1' and '0'.

I notice that whenever I switch to the React native Debbuger on my pc, it uses `webgl` in the backend but without the React native Debbuger it uses rn-webgl'.
I found out by console-logging

```
tf.getBackend())
```

I have tried switching the backend to `CPU` - this turned out to be incredibly slow in the calculation.
I tried waiting for the prediction results from my model while using the CPU backend, I waited so long, I almost fell asleep.
The CPU backend shouldn't be used in production.

I, therefore, had to draw the conclusion that my models' predictions give no predictions without the `WebGL` backend.

My expectations are to get actual model results even without the remote debbugger—something like this below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zAth.png)

How do I get the prediction values?

**My package.json looks like this.**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.0.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm": "^4.1.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "expo": "~44.0.0-beta.0",
    "expo-camera": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.8.6",
    "expo-gl": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-barcode-mask": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-mlkit-ocr": "^0.2.5",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.7"
  }
```

Comment: Can you share an answer to this if you got any? Coz I am getting the same issue, and the inference period is very long (+-2min)

Comment: Yes, I will definitely. @gildniy